# listview getChildAt return wrong child

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm getting some strange behavior from a listview/the getChildAt method.

I have listView and set adapter for it that have 300 rows. I try to set onScrollListener for my list and in onScroll method get firstVisibleItem view and change it's background color.but getChildAt method of list view return wrong view(exactly it return view at **Double of firstVisibleItem**).

here is my code:

```
adapter = new ListAdapterShowContent(this, arrayList);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            View v = list.getChildAt(firstVisibleItem);
            if(v != null) {
                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }

        }
    });
```

for example if firstVisibleItem in onScroll was 3,the Sixth row of list change background

[image]

**UPDATE:** I just change bg for simplify issue, In fact I want to get top position of returned view.so using adapter don't help me.

Comment: think of it that way:  `firstVisibleItem` can be any number from 0 to #items - N while `getChildAt` can be called with a number from 0 to N - 1, where N is a maximum number of items visible in the list,  in another words:  first visible item is always `getChildAt(0)`

Comment: @pskink , I get firstVisibleItem from argument of onScroll method that list pass it to me.also if it return child at 0 position why sixth row change bg?

Comment: if a list view can display 1000 items it doesent mean it has 1000 child views,  it has in typical case 10 or so (N) child views,  so child 0 is always first visible item and child N - 1 is always last visible item,  you can check what N is by calling getChildCount

Comment: @pskink thank you,if you put answer I could accept it.but now I just can say thanks. another question,firstVisibleItem that is in onScroll method ,What used to be؟

Comment: "What used to be" what do you mean?

Comment: sorry,I mean how I can use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to simply call `getChildAt() with index 0` (or 1 if you list view has some fixed header). This will always be the first visible item, regardless of the position of the data behind it in the backing array.

Comment: thanks,it solve my problem.but why work? onScroll firstVisibleItem argument use for what???????

Comment: It is used when you need to access the **data** of the first visible item - you use it in getItem() in the backing adapter. In your case you need the view itself so there's no need for that argument .

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should use

```
Object item = getItemAtPosition(firstVisiblePosition)
```

where `item` is the `data` object behind the row.

Then in the item put up some flag that makes it change the background inside getView of the adapter, and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter, to redraw the list.

You are seeing this problem,because ListView recycles its children.

Comment: thank for you answer,your suggestion will work perfectly, but I need get child view then in onscroll method get it's top position so I can't get help from adapter.I just change bg for simplify issue

Comment: why do you need to get the child view? if you change something in the model, and call notifyDataSetChanged, getView for the given child should be called again, and the view will update

Comment: thank you,your answer true too,sorry that I can't accept two answer.of course I need view for get it's top position. but thank you a lot